# Getting the value and the id of the closest input field

Tags: jquery

I have an edit icon and when clicked this icon invokes a method. In this method I will need the value and the ID attribute's value.
I tried to do this with jquery in a couple of ways, non of which worked.

Here is my html  :

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Enter Phone" readonly="readonly">
        <div class="input-group-addon">
            <span onclick="editUserInfo()"><i  class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the span is clicked, i'd like to get the value of the input field in left, as well as it's id (in this case "phone").

What I tried and didn't work :

For the ID :

```
$('selector').closest('[id]')
```

For the value :

```
$(this).parent().find('.form-control').val();
```

Of course, I tried many variations of there, but nothing worked(i am very new to this).

Comment: I want to use the same method for all the input fields in my form.

Comment: Are there multiple elements in `document` which have `id` `"phone"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the current element that was clicked (using `onclick="editUserInfo(this)"`), this way you can use that element as a reference inside your function. Otherwise - the `this` variable will reference to the `window` object, (which is not what you are looking for).

Inside the function you can find the `input.form-control` by going to the parent element that has the `input-group` class.

Check this example:

```js
function editUserInfo(el) {
  input_element = $(el).parents('.input-group').find('input.form-control');
  console.log(input_element.attr('id'));
  console.log(input_element.val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-2">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Enter Phone" readonly="readonly">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
      <span onclick="editUserInfo(this)"><i  class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true">click</i></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> I added the `click` text inside the `<span>` tag only for visibility...

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! It worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 2):

Note, `id` of element within `document` should be unique. If there is only one element in `document` which has `id` `"phone"`, then you could simply use `$("#phone")` to select the element. Else, substitute `class` for `id` at `<input>` elements, then use

```
this.parentElement.previousElementSibling
```

within `".input-group span"` `click` event handler to select `<input>` element which is previous sibling of parent `.input-group-addon` element.

Note also that the `<input>` element does not have a `value` set at `html`.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".input-group span").on("click", function() {
    var input = $(this.parentElement.previousElementSibling);
    var data = {
      "id": input.attr("id"), // `.attr("class")`
      "value": input.val()
    };
    console.log(data);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-2">
  <div class="input-group">
    <!-- `id` should be unique, change to `class` if multiple `id` set to `"phone"` in `document` -->
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Enter Phone" readonly="readonly" value="123-456-7890">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
      <span><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true">click</i></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use closest to find the closest ancestor matching the given selector
Then use find to find the input with the given name using the attribute equals selector.
Example

```html
<div class="options">
  <div class="phone">
     <label>Phone:</label>
     <input type="text" name="phone" value="1"/>
  </div>
```

```
var val = $(this).closest("div.options").find("input[name='phone']").val();
```